# Change elements of list based on list of indices

Tags: python, list, nested, indices

How can a list of indices (called "indlst"), such as [[1,0], [3,1,2]] which corresponds to elements [1][0] and [3][1][2] of a given list (called "lst"), be used to CHANGE their respective elements in the original list? Also note that the indices refer to elements which are nested to an arbitrary depth. For example, given

```
indlst = [[1,0], [3,1,2]]
lst = ["a", ["b","c"], "d", ["e", ["f", "g", "h"]]]
required_output = [lst[1][0],lst[3][1][2]]
```

The output should correspond to ["b","h"]. I know I can get this far with the following snippet (see [Use list of nested indices to access list element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40944373/use-list-of-nested-indices-to-access-list-element)):

```
for i in indlst:
    temp = lst
    for j in i:
        temp = temp[j]
    print(temp)
b
h
```

However, I need to CHANGE these elements within the the original list. For example, changing each of the accessed elements to "CHANGED":

```
changed_lst = ["a", ["CHANGED","c"], "d", ["e", ["f", "g", "CHANGED"]]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check for the innermost index in each sequence - when you reach it, 
change the value, instead of going deeper in the sequence and just retriveing the element:

```
for indices in indlst:
    base = lst
    for i, index in enumerate(indices):
        if i == len(indices) - 1:
            base[index] = "CHANGED"
            break
        base = base[index]
```

This alternate form might be more elegant, alhtough it is just the samething:

```
for indices in indlst:
    base = lst
    for index in indices[:-1]: 
        base = base[index]
    base[indices[-1]] = "CHANGED"
```

Comment: Though correct, I wouldn't consider this a Pythonic solution

Comment: And what is magic about the number three there? This works up to arbitrary depths.

Comment: @jsbueno I've done a couple more tests and it seems like I was wrong. The first couple tests I did seemed to show that it didn't word with depths of three and under but now it seems I was wrong.  I will edit my post. Sorry for spreading that misconception.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, an element in `indlst` is a list of indices to find a particular element in `lst` so you can simply iterate through a element of `indlst` to find a reference to the item in `lst` that you want to change.

```
def set_item_by_index_list(index_list, list_to_change, new_val):
    l = list_to_change

    # the last index in index_list is the actual item so we don't need
    # to index into it.
    for idx in index_list[:-1]:
        l = l[idx]

    l[index_list[-1]] = new_val

indlst = [[1,0], [3,1,2]]
lst = ["a", ["b","c"], "d", ["e", ["f", "g", "h"]]]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print lst
    set_item_by_index_list(indlst[0], lst, "BEER")
    print lst

    set_item_by_index_list(indlst[1], lst, "WHISKEY")
    print lst
```

The above code yields:

```
['a', ['b', 'c'], 'd', ['e', ['f', 'g', 'h']]]
['a', ['b', 'BEER'], 'd', ['e', ['f', 'g', 'h']]]
['a', ['b', 'BEER'], 'd', ['e', ['f', 'WHISKEY', 'h']]]
```

Comment: Note that the output is different from the OP's desired result. I think you need to replace `l[idx] = new_val` with `l[index_list[-1]] = new_val`

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the error. You are correct. I've updated the answer.

Comment: You should avoid nameing varibales as `l` - they are hardly distinguishible from `1` in a lot of fonts and impair readability. (Even in fonts where they are distinct, and even though "1" would result in a syntax error - it is readability we are talking about)

Comment: @timotree: can you clarify this thing about the depth being larger than 3 you are comenting around? This is just the same algorithm I had used, and it does not depend on the listing depth.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to access the innermost list without explicit loops.

```
from functools import reduce

indlst = [[1,0], [3,1,2]]
lst = ["a", ["b","c"], "d", ["e", ["f", "g", "h"]]]

for inds in indllst:
  innermost_list = reduce(lambda l, r: l[r], inds[:-1], lst)
  innermost_list[inds[-1]] = 'CHANGED'
```

Answer (score 0):

### My thinking

My solution was to start at the deepest element and work our way back as follows:

- Insert deepest element into the second deepest element
- Insert the modified second deepest element into the third deepest element
- etc.

### Some code that does that

```
def set_from_indices(value, indices, array):
    for i in reversed(range(len(indices))): # Pulls back the deepest element available each loop
        current = array.copy() # Without .copy() any changes to current would also change array.
        for index, indice in enumerate(indices):
            if index == i: # If we are on the deepest element available this loop
                current[indice] = value.copy() if isinstance(value, list) else value # Without the .copy() current[indice] just becomes '...'
                value = current.copy() # Make the 
                break
            current = current[indice]
    return value

indlst = [[0,1], [0,0,1], [0,0,0,1]]
lst = [[[[4,3],2],1],0]
for indices in indlst:
    lst = set_from_indices("CHANGED", indices, lst)
```