# A function that takes a nested list and a list of indices, and returns an lvalue (a reference) to the element at the specified indices

Tags: python

I want a function that takes a nested list and a list of indices, and returns an lvalue (a reference) to the element at the specified indices.

rvalue version of this is:

```
def part(lst,*ind):
    res = lst
    for i in ind:
        res = res[i]
    return res
```

```
a = ['a',['b','c']]
print(part(a,1))
#['b','c']
print(part(a,1,0))
#'b'
```

I want a lvalue version of this so that I can write the following `apply` function using similar logic.

```
def apply(lst,f,ind):
    lval = part_lval(lst,*ind)
    lval = f(lval)
```

```
a = ['a',['b','c']]
print(apply(a,f,[1]))
#['a',f(['b','c'])]
print(apply(a,f,[1,0]))
#['a',[f('b'),'c']]
```

In python it's fine to do this:
`a[1][0] = f(a[1][0])`
I want to do the same thing using a list of indices `[1,0]`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. I don't think `part` works the way you think it does.

Comment: The terms "lvalue" and "rvalue" don't really have any meaning in Python, at least not in the way they do in C++. You might want to read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html, then rethink what you are asking.

Comment: Python doesn't work that way.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how to get a pointer to an item in a list so you can modify them through that pointer. You can't do that in Python. What you do is pass the list and the index(es) or slice objects you want to modify. Wrap that in a little class if you want, or just use a tuple.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a reference to a variable in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222440/how-to-create-a-reference-to-a-variable-in-python)

Comment: Dou you really want that `part_lval` function, or just the `apply` function?

Comment: @KellyBundy I want `apply` function. I broke down the problem to make it a more generic problem. thanks.

Comment: You rather made this an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Except at  least you mentioned your X as well. That can be done, no problem. But that's not what your question asks for.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to make `apply` function thanks to this post. [Change elements of list based on list of indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40954458/change-elements-of-list-based-on-list-of-indices?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
def apply(f,lst,ind):
    base = lst
    for i in ind[:-1]:
        base = base[i]
    base[ind[-1]] = f(base[ind[-1]])
```

```
a = ['a',['b','c']]
apply(str.upper,a,[1,0])
#['a',['B','c']]
```

Thanks